# Unable to install RTools with installr, in RStudio

Tags: r, rtools, installr

I am working on HPC with `RSTudio` 4.2.1 and I want to install `RTools` with the `installr` package.
I was able to install the `installr` but then, when I run the command `install.Rtools()` I get the following:

```
Infiniband hardware address can be incorrect! Please read BUGS section in ifconfig(8).
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42-x86_64.exe' 


Warning message:
In download_fun(exe_URL, destfile = exe_filename, quiet = FALSE,  :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42-x86_64.exe': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

I installed the `installr` using `devtools::install_github('talgalili/installr')`

If anyone run into this, I would really need some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a known bug as reported in

https://github.com/talgalili/installr/issues/177

since the link of fetching the rtools has been changed.

You can wait until the authors of the `installr` package fix it or manually download the r tools and follow the steps.

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/